# mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server /: Name or service not known

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab, nfs

I'm trying to switch CIFS protocol with NFS in order to mount partition ( shared windows folder most likely , not sure ). I want to do this, because with CIFS I am required to use credentials , which will expire soon. Content of /etc/fstab :

```
UUID=c89643e8-ac97-11e8-8d9f-00155d004c13 / ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=c7692878-ac97-11e8-8d9f-00155d004c13 /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=B02C-6926 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 0
//10.95.176.67:/DataStore  /mnt/DataStore nfs iocharset=utf8,rw,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,cache=strict,domain=BOE,uid=1000,noforceuid,gid=1000,noforcegid,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,actimeo=1 0  0
```

So I switched cifs with nfs, and deleted credentials from /etc/fstab. But i get this error :

```
$> mount  /mnt/DataStore
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server //10.95.176.67: Name or service not known
```

With CIFS I was able to mount perfectly.
Does anybody know how to fix this ?

Tnx.

EDIT:

```
tcpdump host 10.95.176.67

15:04:35.906115 IP is2.695 > netapp01-1.boecillo.eemea.ericsson.se.635: Flags [S], seq 211338160, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1271784599 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:04:36.932328 IP is2.695 > netapp01-1.boecillo.eemea.ericsson.se.635: Flags [S], seq 211338160, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1271785625 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:04:38.948352 IP is2.695 > netapp01-1.boecillo.eemea.ericsson.se.635: Flags [S], seq 211338160, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1271787641 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:04:43.172356 IP is2.695 > netapp01-1.boecillo.eemea.ericsson.se.635: Flags [S], seq 211338160, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1271791865 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:04:51.364376 IP is2.695 > netapp01-1.boecillo.eemea.ericsson.se.635: Flags [S], seq 211338160, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1271800057 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:05:07.492394 IP is2.695 > netapp01-1.boecillo.eemea.ericsson.se.635: Flags [S], seq 211338160, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1271816185 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Comment: You don't put `//` in front for `nfs`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure a NFS mounting in fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890981/how-to-configure-a-nfs-mounting-in-fstab)

Comment: NFS is a different protocol to SaMBa so does your file-server provide both services/protocols?   You can't just make a change on the client & have it work (unless both are supported by the server).

Comment: If i lose the // then i get : mount.nfs: Connection timed out

Comment: Does `showmount -e 10.95.176.67` work? If not, you may need to open the server's nfs and portmapper ports. See for example [NFS Client Unable to Mount Shared Directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498528/nfs-client-unable-to-mount-shared-directory)

Comment: To the showmount command i get this : "rpc mount export: RPC: Timed out"

Comment: it seems that I can telnet on 10.95.176.67 on ports 2049 and 111, does this mean NFS server is running on the other side ?

Comment: I posted tcpdump output ( for the showmount command ) in the main post,  it seems that packets are not returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you started NFS server and exported the DataStore location on the //10.95.176.67 server.  If it was using cifs/samba before then maybe nfs isn't enabled and configured.

Comment: I will try to check if NFS is installed on the remote server, for the moment I don't have access to it, but what do you mean by exporting the DataStore location on the server ? I don't understand this.

Comment: You need to have an nfs server daemon running on the server but you also need to configure that to share the parts of the filesystem which you want to see.  These are typically configured in the file /etc/exports, this lists which servers can access the shares and also what sort of access they get.